# ignoring files except in a specific directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I am creating a LaTeX document which includes PDF images; so, I'd like to ignore the generated PDFs but not the source PDFs. I have actually managed to do this, but the first thing I tried didn't work, and I'd like to know why.

The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) says, in part:

> Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These patterns match relative to the location of the .gitignore file. A project normally includes such .gitignore files in its repository, containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.

...but I can't seem to get the deeper `.gitignore` files to override shallower ones. Here's a simple sequence of commands to reproduce what I'm seeing:

```
~% mkdir git-test
~% cd git-test
~/git-test% git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dmwit/git-test/.git/
~/git-test% echo '*.pdf' >.gitignore
~/git-test% mkdir images
~/git-test% touch images/.gitignore
~/git-test% git add .gitignore images/.gitignore 
~/git-test% git commit -m "example .gitignore files"
[master (root-commit) 8c7e91d] example .gitignore files
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 images/.gitignore
~/git-test% touch images/foo.pdf
~/git-test% git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Why is the working directory clean after this? Shouldn't the empty `.gitignore` file in `git-test/images/` override the one in `images/`, resulting in nothing in that directory being ignored? (Also, for what it's worth, after deleting `git-test/.gitignore`, the new `pdf` does appear in `git status`, so I don't believe any of my global exclusions are affecting this.)

Comment: I'm sure you considered this, but just in-case: can you generate the files to another directory outside of Git's reach?  If so, this just makes since in so many ways.

Comment: Or just in directory inside the git repo dedicated to them — it would take one line in .gitignore to include it.

Comment: @golergka Yup, as mentioned in the question, I managed to do what I need to do (simply by putting something like `*.pdf;!images/*.pdf` in my top-level `.gitignore` file). I'm still curious why the approach outlined in the question doesn't work, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` doesn't override complete `.gitignore` files in subdirectories. It adds the contents of those files to the current ignore rules. In your particular case, the empty `.gitignore` file is incorporated into the ignore list when processing that subdirectory (and any of its subdirectories...), but since there are no rules in that file, it's a no-op. I would suggest either a) try putting `"!*.pdf"` in that `.gitignore` file to tell it not to ignore PDF files there, or b) get rid of the top-level `*.pdf` ignore rule, rearrange your build process to put the produced PDF files in a separate directory (e.g. `output/`) and then put a `.gitignore` there with the "*.pdf" rule in it.